# How do I append to a macro multiple times?

Tags: c++, boost-preprocessor

With the `boost preprocessor` library I can do things like this:

```
#define ARRAY (3, (a, b, c))
BOOST_PP_ARRAY_PUSH_BACK(ARRAY, d) // this expands to a, b, c, d
```

But how do I do this multiple times? Say I want to `push_back` more than once, in different parts of my code, and then display the result?

The following code just prints out `dummy`:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>

#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

#define ARRAY (1, (dummy))

BOOST_PP_ARRAY_PUSH_BACK(ARRAY, 1)
BOOST_PP_ARRAY_PUSH_BACK(ARRAY, 1)
BOOST_PP_ARRAY_PUSH_BACK(ARRAY, 1)

int main()
{
    std::cout << BOOST_PP_ARRAY_ENUM(ARRAY);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`BOOST_PP_ARRAY_PUSH_BACK` doesn't actually modify the `ARRAY`; it simply expands to the `ARRAY` with the new element appended.  So, for example, given:

```
#define ARRAY (1, (dummy))
```

this:

```
BOOST_PP_ARRAY_PUSH_BACK(ARRAY, 1)
```

expands to:

```
(2, (dummy, 1))
```

but `ARRAY` will still expand to:

```
(1, (dummy))
```

You can't modify the replacement list of `ARRAY` via macro replacement.

Comment: Ok, so you're saying it's not possible?

Comment: @Jason, Macros are like pure functions. You can make a macro, say `PUSH_BACK_N(array, times, elem)` that expands to `BOOST_PP_ARRAY_PUSH_BACK(BOOST_PP_ARRAY_PUSH_BACK(…(ARRAY, elem)…), elem), elem)`. I'm not sure if there's a way of doing that much cleaner than a couple `BOOST_PP_REPEAT` calls.

Comment: @chris but to do this I need to have all the calls available at the outset right? I mean, I can't just add to an `ARRAY` on the fly and then print out the result whenever I want?

Comment: @Jason, Right, but you can define a macro as a push onto it, and another macro as a push onto that and so on.

Comment: @chris but I can't programatically do this, can I? That would require a preprocessor directive in a macro function, which isn't allowed?

Comment: @Jason, Where does it require a directive in a macro? `#define PUSHED_ARRAY BOOST_PP_ARRAY_PUSH_BACK(ARRAY, 1)` allows you to do `#define PUSHED2_ARRAY BOOST_PP_ARRAY_PUSH_BACK(PUSHED_ARRAY, 1)`. Enumerating `PUSHED2_ARRAY` will go through both pushed elements.

Comment: @chris that won't work for me because then I need to keep track of the new name at every step, I want the user to be able to simply call `SOME_OP(2)` and then the array to have its old content with `2` on the end..

Comment: @Jason, Well, no, it's not that simple for the user, but they can still use a `#define` to "store" it. I think you could technically do something like what Boost does with `BOOST_PP_COUNTER` (which uses `BOOST_PP_SLOT`) and have the user do `#define PUSHED_VALUE 2` and `#include SOME_OP()`.